# Type mismatch runtime error (13) for vba

Tags: vba, excel

I want to do filter for the region and delete the rest of the rows that don't match the region. The sheet has no formulas in it only values and characters. This is part of the larger codes I am working on so I am only going to post this part and this is the first time I have seen the error so for other worksheets they work just fine the way I declared.

The line that has an error and won't pass through is here `If InStr(1, Rng10.Cells(q, 1).Value, "NW") = 0 Then`

My data has a helper column which is W and I am filtering it. I made sure there is no duplicate for the variables I used. (I used, s, t, m, n and etc...) I tried to declare q as double or variate and neither of them don't work.

```
sub test()
Worksheets("A").Activate
    'filter
    Dim sh9 As Worksheet
    Set sh9 = Sheets("A")
    Dim LR16 As Long
    Dim Rng10 As Range
    Dim q As Long
    LR16 = sh9.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng10 = Range("W5:W" & LR16 - 1)
    For q = Rng10.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    If InStr(1, Rng10.Cells(q, 1).Value, "NW") = 0 Then
    Rng10.Cells(q, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    Next q
end sub
```

Comment: Will your code work if you change your mentioned line into `If InStr(1, Rng10.Cells(q, 1).Value, "NW") < 1 Then`? And are you sure that the mentioned cells contains Strings?

Comment: its still giving me the same error, column W has values like NW, N East, SE, and #N/A however, my previous sheets has the same situations and I did not have this issue.

Comment: There's your error. Your cell contains an error displayed as "#N/A", not text that *is* "#N/A".

Comment: Presumably, if you have #N/A appearing on sheets where this worked, you've Copy/Paste special - Values those errors into the text "#N/A"

Comment: should I put On Error Resume Next in the first line to avoid it?

Comment: Don't use `On Error Resume Next` unless you have no other option. See my answer for a simple alternative.

Comment: @sc1324 `On Error Resume Next` is pretty much ***always*** a bad idea.

Comment: I just went back and checked my sheets, none of them has the #N/A in the helper column and maybe that's why it worked so far. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `.Value`, use `.Text` to see errors as text equivalent.

Change

```
If InStr(1, Rng10.Cells(q, 1).Value, "NW") = 0 Then
```

To

```
If InStr(1, Rng10.Cells(q, 1).Text, "NW") = 0 Then
```

Comment: I will modify my codes for every work sheet so in case in the future I have a similar problem. Thanks your codes work perfectly.

Comment: That's probably perfect for OP's needs - however if you find yourself in a situation where you're verifying the string value to see if it's `"#N/A"`, I'd warmly recommend a strongly-typed approach that uses the range's `Value` instead of its text representation.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> If InStr(1, Rng10.Cells(q, 1).Value, "NW") = 0 Then
> ```

You're assuming what the type of `Rng10.Cells(q, 1).Value` is going to be, and you're assuming that whatever that type is, VBA can implicitly convert it to a `String` to pass to the `InStr` function.

When a cell contains an error value (`#N/A`, `#VALUE!`, `#REF!` or any other error), then the type of `thatCell.Value` is `Error` - and VBA does NOT know how to convert `Error` values to `String` values (or anything else for that matter), so it raises run-time error 13 *type mismatch* and forces you to fix your code instead.

You can check if a cell's value is an `Error` using the `IsError` function:

```
Dim myValue As Variant
myValue = Rng10.Cells(q, 1).Value
If IsError(myValue) Then
    'cell contains an error
Else
    'cell contains no error: myValue is safe to convert to a string
    If InStr(1, CStr(myValue), "NW") = 0 Then
        '...
    End If
End If
```

Side note, notice how [*proper indentation*](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation) makes the code easier to follow.