# Getting a mismatch error on: If InStr(1, cel.Value, "Mgnt Fee") > 0 Then

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently getting a mismatch error for the last InStr function in this code, but I have no idea why it doesn't work when the other two InStr functions work. I made sure the "Mgnt Fee" string does exist in the specified range. It works if I put the "Mgnt Fee" in the range K12:K200, but I need to do it in the J column. For reference the K column contains names and the J column contains formulas minus the "Mgnt Fee" string. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ListBill").Activate

For Each cel In Range("K12:K200").Cells
    If IsEmpty(cel.Offset(0, -1)) = True And InStr(1, cel.Value, "Brose Tuscaloosa Plant 1") < 1 And InStr(1, cel.Value, "Brose Tuscaloosa") < 1 Then
        cel.Offset(0, -1).Formula = "=INDEX(GLCodes!Q:Q,MATCH(INDIRECT(""RC[1]"",0),GLCodes!C:C,0))"
    End If
Next
For Each cel In Range("K12:K200").Cells
    If IsEmpty(cel.Offset(0, -1)) = True And InStr(1, cel.Value, "Brose Tuscaloosa") > 0 Then
        cel.Offset(0, -1).Formula = "=INDEX(GLCodes!Q:Q,MATCH(INDIRECT(""RC[6]"",0),GLCodes!C:C,0))"
    End If
Next
For Each cel In Range("J12:J200").Cells
    If InStr(1, cel.Value, "Mgnt Fee") > 0 Then
        Range("AR4") = cel.Offset(0, 29).Value
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Are there any error values in cells J12:J200?

Comment: there are #N/A values

Comment: Ok, that's why you get an error. Add an extra `If` above the `If InStr(1, cel.Value, "Mgnt Fee") > 0 Then`: `If Not IsError(cel.Value) Then`, and also add the required `End If`.

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43615535) a great answer in the linked thread explaining why you get an error, and demonstrating the fix.